# Development environment for Linux wireless using sparse

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ide

I am used to Eclipse and Visual studio for development for Java and C#. I am looking forward to modify and compile some files in C in the Linux Wireless subsystem. The site recommends using Sparse but there isn't much documentation regarding it. Can Sparse be used as a development environment like Eclipse. Any documentation regarding this?

Comment: A link to the site would be helpful. As of now, I cannot find anything called "sparse" that is an IDE

Comment: I guess it isn't an IDE. Following is the link. [Sparse](http://linuxwireless.org/en/developers/Documentation/using-sparse#Using_sparse-1). Any recommendations for an IDE?

Comment: Try vim + ctags or emacs. KDevelop should also be able to handle that amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of the page you linked to:

```
Sparse is a semantic parser and static analyzer utility [...]
```

Sparse is **not** an IDE, but a command line programme that checks your C code for static type errors.
It has been specifically developed for use within the Linux kernel.

[See here for a how to guide](http://elinux.org/Sparse).